# NodeJS MongoDB Mongoose - Getting _.id of newly created Schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an app that allows users to rate books. The books are called from Google Books API. I only save a copy of the book in my DB when the user submits their rating.

```
reviews.put("/:id/new", async (req, res) => {
  let url = await `https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/${req.params.id}`;
  console.log(url);
  await request(url, { json: true }, async (error, response, data) => {
    let newRating;
    Book.findOne({ id: req.params.id }, (err, result) => {
      if (err) console.log(err.message);
      if (result) {
        if (req.body.stars !== undefined) {
          newRating = /* some math formula */
        } else {
          newRating = /* some math formula */
        }
      } else {
        newRating = req.body.stars;
      }
    });
    Book.findOneAndUpdate(
      {
        id: req.params.id
      },
      {
        id: data.id,
        id: data.id,
        title: data.volumeInfo.title,
        description: data.volumeInfo.description,
        img: data.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail,
        author: data.volumeInfo.authors,
        rating: newRating,
        $inc: {
          ratingCount: 1
        }
      },
      {
        upsert: true,
        returnNewDocument: true
      },
      (err, book) => {
        console.log(book) // If its creating a new document, book returns null. If the book is already in the DB, book returns the document. 
        Review.create({
          rating: req.body.stars,
          review: req.body.review,
          reviewer: req.session.currentUser._id,
          book: book._id // <-- ERROR, cannot read property "_.id" of null
        });
      }
    );
  });

  res.redirect("/");
});
```

The issue is that `book` returns `null` when it's newly created. But this works fine if someone else has already rated it. I've tried using `.save()` but that did not work. How else can I get the `_.id` of the newly created book?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing through the incorrect [query options](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate). You need to be using:

`new`: bool - if true, return the modified document rather than the original.

`upsert`: bool - creates the object if it doesn't exist. defaults to false.

Update the method as follows:

```
Book.findOneAndUpdate(
      {
        id: req.params.id
      },
      {
        id: data.id,
        id: data.id,
        title: data.volumeInfo.title,
        description: data.volumeInfo.description,
        img: data.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail,
        author: data.volumeInfo.authors,
        rating: newRating,
        $inc: {
          ratingCount: 1
        }
      },
      {
        upsert: true,
        new: true
      },
      (err, book) => {
        console.log(book) // If its creating a new document, book returns null. If the book is already in the DB, book returns the document. 
        Review.create({
          rating: req.body.stars,
          review: req.body.review,
          reviewer: req.session.currentUser._id,
          book: book.id // <-- ERROR, cannot read property "_.id" of null
        });
      }
```

See the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate)

Answer (score 0):

Use `'new': true` like this: `{ upsert: true, 'new': true }`.

This should return upserted document.